# how to create new instance of a fragment which has dagger inject

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment, dagger-2

Hi I am injecting `mainActivityViewModel` into my fragment using constructor injection, I have a companion object within the fragment which creates an instance of the fragment.
how can I create instance from the main activity

RetroComponent - dagger

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [RetroModule::class])
interface RetroComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel)
}
```

Fragment

```
class CreditScoreFragment @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
) : Fragment() {

    private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModel.getCreditReport()
    }

   companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            CreditScoreFragment(viewModel).apply {

            }

    }
}
```

Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupFragment()
    }

    private fun setupFragment() {
        val fragment = CreditScoreFragment.newInstance()
        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

How should I call CreditScoreFragment.newInstance() and how to pass the `MainActivityViewModel` which is required for the fragment

thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late response but I will answer it anyways in case if you are still wondering. We don't have access to constructors of Android components so you can't use it in this way. Dagger provides few injection types, here you can find f.e field injection which will works like a charm in your case.

LINK: https://medium.com/@alexxpasta/android-using-dagger-2-with-kotlin-part1-field-injection-58b0ba97925a